# Connecting subplots with lines in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Consider the following example code:

```
load sumsin; 
s = sumsin+10; % example data series
time = linspace(0,5*24,1000);

figure(1);
subplot(311);
plot(time,s,'k');

subplot(312);
plot(time,s,'k');
hold on;
[s_denoised,~, ~] = wden(s,'minimaxi','s','sln',1,'db4');
plot(time,s_denoised,'r');

subplot(313);
plot(time,s,'k');
hold on;
plot(time,s_denoised,'r');
xlim([20 40]);
```

Resulting in
[image]

I would like to alter this plot by inserting lines between subplot 2 and 3 to show that subplot 3 is a portion of subplot2. For example:

[image]

How can this be achieved in matlab?

Edit:

I was thinking of something along the lines of generating a invisible axes over the entire figure, obtain the position of each subplot, the location of 20 and 40 will be a certain percentage of the subplot width so I could use the annotation command from here to start a line and then apply the same method to the third subplot to connect the lines with the desired location. I have trying this, but no solution so far.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/annotation-objects.html I think you could rework this example to achieve what you're after.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just for the sake of the answer, you could use [`annotation objects`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) to get the effect that you're looking for, as correctly suggested in a comment. Note that their coordinates have to be normalized to the [0, 1] range with respect to the figure window, so it might be quite tedious to adjust them.

This *does* get the job done, but it's horrible. Don't do it this way.

#### Example

Since I don't have your original data, I'll draw something of my own (but similar to yours):

```
t = linspace(0, 120, 1000);
s_denoised = sin(t / 2);
s = s_denoised + 0.2 * randn(size(s_denoised));
subplot(3, 1, 1), plot(t, s, 'k')    
subplot(3, 1, 2), plot(t, s, 'k', t, s_denoised, 'r')    
subplot(3, 1, 3), plot(t, s, 'k', t, s_denoised, 'r'), xlim([20 40])
```

Now let's add "annotation" lines like you want:

```
annotation('doublearrow', [.26 .39], [.38 .38]); %// Top double-arrow line
annotation('doublearrow', [.13 .9], [.34 .34]);  %// Bottom double-arrow line
annotation('line', [.325 .325], [.38 .37]);      %// Top little connector
annotation('line', [.515 .515], [.35 .34]);      %// Bottom little connector
annotation('line', [.325 .515], [.37 .35]);      %// Line
```

Result:

[image: result image]

Comment: +1 for dealing with the annotation objects! I keep waiting for the release when they're actually useful (hint: it's not R2013a).

Comment: good answer, although it would be useful to not have to define the individual start and end points of the lines. Use the position of the subplots in the figure window perhaps?

Comment: In the example in the link I posted they use something like p1 = get(h1,'Position');
t1 = get(h1,'TightInset'); to get the coordinates of the borders of the subplots but I couldn't get anything sensible out of that. How did you determine the coordinates? Trial and error? Or is there a systematic way?

Comment: @Dan If (0,0) is the top left corner of the figure window and (1,1) is the bottom right, then you can have a pretty good sense of what coordinates objects would have at different locations. I still had to resort to trial and error to adjust everything, though (took about 20 minutes or so).

Comment: @EitanT Can you please update your answer for Matlab 2015b or 2016a, please. I think this can be done now better.

Comment: @Masi Unfortunately I don't have these MATLAB versions available :(

Comment: @EitanT I have. Feel free to update the body and I run you the codes if necessary.

Comment: @Masi Thanks. I'll consider this once I get a bit of free time in the near future ;)

Answer (score 6):

A bit late in the game, but still it can be beneficial to know of these optional tools that are available at the file exchange (FEX):

**[inset2DAbsolute](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33159-inset2dabsolute)** - creates an axes inset, defined using the larger axes, and corresponding annotations.

[image]

**[On-figure magnifier](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26007-on-figure-magnifier)** - is a zooming tool for 2D graphics of images on the same plot. It is composed of two blocks (the secondary axes and the magnifier). The secondary axes, which can be arbitrarily allocated within the limits of the figure, displays the area marked by the magnifier.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

However, from my experience, beautification of graphs and plots can be done more efficiently using graphics software.
I usually use excel + powerpoint for this purpose.

Therefore, my advice (which is not exactly a good answer for your question) is:

- export your data to excel, using [`xlswrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html)
- use excel to create the desired plots.
- copy-paste the plots to power point for "hand-crafted" finishing...

Comment: Excel graphics? Anyway, you can make rather nice graphs in Matlab (and you have a lot more options than in Excel), but for prettifying, I suggest creating something decent in Matlab, save as eps, then improve it in Illustrator (or your vector graphics program of your chouce)